How to link suppliers and products as separate dimensions in a data warehouse when only product ID is present in transactions?
I'm working on a data warehouse project where we have a Products table that currently stores information about both suppliers and products. I'm considering separating them into distinct dimensions (Supplier and Product), but I'm facing a challenge with mapping these dimensions when handling transactions.because i am working with star schema.
In the transaction data, we only have the product_id, without any direct reference to the supplier. Given this structure:
Should I store a supplier ID within the Product dimension to maintain the link?
How would I design this to efficiently support queries that involve both product and supplier information? because i have olap queries like best supplier and all.
What are the best practices for managing such relationships in a data warehouse schema?
Any advice on how to approach this would be appreciated.
i have made star schema with supplier and product as two different dimensions. i have also loded product data by splitting it in two tables.but now i am confused how to coonect supplier dimension directly from transactions ..or  i should just remove supplier dimension and add that as column in product dimenson

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
